# Converting and using Shadertoy's iResolution variable in a Three.js script

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I'm converting a [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsScDd) to a local Three.js project, and can't get it to render. You can try out the [full snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44295602/2441384) here.

I think the problem may lie in how I'm converting the `iResolution` variable. As I understand it, the built-in Shadertoy global variable `iResolution` contains the pixel dimensions of the window. Here is how `iResolution` is used in the [original Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsScDd):

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.y;
vec2 ak = abs(fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy-0.5);
```

In converting this Shadertoy into a local Three.js-based script I have tried two approaches to converting `iResolution`:

**1)** Loading the window dimensions as a Vector2 and sending them into the shader as the uniform `vec2 uResolution`:

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.y;
vec2 ak = abs(gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy-0.5);
```

This solution sticks closest to the design of the [original Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MsScDd), but alas nothing renders.

**2)** The second approach comes from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105581/2441384) and converts the `uv` coordinates to `xy` absolute coordinates:

```
vec2 uvCustom = -1.0 + 2.0 *vUv;
vec2 ak = abs(gl_FragCoord.xy / uvCustom.xy-0.5);
```

In this one, I admit I don't fully understand how it works, and my use of the `uvCustom` in the second line may not be correct.

In the end, nothing renders onscreen except a Three.js CameraHelper I'm using. Otherwise, the screen is black and the console shows no errors for the Javascript or WebGL. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: can you make a js fiddle that can be modified?

Comment: Change your shader to just `void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1); }`. Do you see red? If not the issue has nothing to do with your fragment shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you don't need to even do this division. If you are using a full screen quad (`PlaneBufferGeometry`), you can render it with just the uvs:

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.y;
vec2 vUv = varyingUV;

uv == vUv; //sort of
```

your vertex shader can look something like this

```
varying vec2 varyingUV;

void main(){
  varyingUV = uv;
  gl_Position = vec4( position.xy , 0. , 1.);
}
```

If you make a `new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2,1,1);` this should render as a full screen quad